Does Young's interference experiment require transversal wave?
In the classical Young's interference experiment, it is assumed that a wave front reaches two slits at the same time.  Does this mean that the wave has to be a transverse wave?

While Young's interference experiment can be done using EM wave, can it be done using acoustic wave? I could not find any literature on this experiment. Specifically, I question that if we need interaction between the two slits for the interference to happen, e.g., the two slits have to be very close to each other for the interference to happen.
What if the slits are not perpendicular to the wave direction, so that different wave front reaches each slit simultaneously, will there be an interference pattern? I guess if we use Lazer to do this experiment, we can still see interference because the coherence of Lazer.  But we will not see interference using normal light. On the other hand, acoustic wave should produce interference pattern.

What is your answer?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/834652/

You can hear interference 'fringes' by connecting two loud speakers to the same signal generator and walking around the area.
At some positions the sound will be loud and at others it will be faint.
By taking suitable measurement you can measure the wavelength of the sound and then knowing the frequency of the sound you can evaluate the speed of sound.
Video
Using two signal generators set at slightly different frequencies you can hear a moving interference pattern with the phenomena also called beats.
What if the slits are not perpendicular to the wave direction, so that different wave front reaches each slit simultaneously, will there be an interference pattern?
There will still be an interference pattern but it will be displaced.
——
Added after the question was changed.
The fringe separation depends on the wavelength of the waves which are interfering with the ‘standard’’ two slit formula for the fringe separation applying.  So for sound waves of wavelength one metre the separation of the loudspeakers should be of (fractions of) metres. The is no ‘interaction’ between the two slits other than they are ‘close’ together of order the wavelength of the sound.

I do not question that acoustic wave can interfere.  I question that if we need interaction between the two slits for the interference to happen, e.g., the two slits have to be very close to each other for the interference to happen.  I will modify my question to make this point clearer.

The fringe separation depends on the wavelength of the waves which are interfering with the ‘standard’’ two slit formula for the fringe separation applying.  So for sound waves of wavelength one metre the separation of the loudspeakers should be of (fractions of) metres. The is no ‘interaction’ between the two slits other than they are ‘close’ together of order the wavelength of the sound.

It may surprise you, but the double-slit experiment (or bird's feather experiment, with which it was first performed) has nothing to do with interference. In case of interference


In places where the waves cancel each other out, there is destructive interference. Constructive interference prevails in places where they reinforce each other.


This is correct for mechanical waves, but does not apply to light or electromagnetic radiation.
Let me explain why.
There is a fantastic experiment in which the light intensity is dimmed to such an extent that photons only reach the double slit one at a time. The impacts of the photons can be identified as individual dots on a receiving instrument.
After a while, it becomes visible that the photons move towards certain areas under the influence of the slits and that the probability of them reaching others is close to zero. We obtain a fringe pattern with changing intensity distribution on the observation screen.
Some special phenomena are also worth mentioning in this context:

the experiment also works with electrons, which are just as indivisible particles as photons
the experiment to change the intensity distribution also works on a single edge; a fringe pattern forms behind it.

This allows us to draw a few conclusions for EM radiation and for subatomic particles:

there is no amplification and extinction of waves or their components; there are no waves involved at all
it is not necessary or possible to explain the intensity distribution at edges with interference; however, it is a wonderfully simple calculation method
the interaction between the surface electrons of the edge(s) with their electric and magnetic field components and the particle current should be included in the consideration. The description of the slit experiments by phononic $^*)$ phenomen and all its varieties is far advanced.

$^*)$ A phonon is a collective excitation in a periodic, elastic arrangement of atoms or molecules in condensed matter.

What if the slits are not perpendicular to the wave direction, so that different wave front reaches each slit simultaneously, will there be an interference pattern?

This is where it gets interesting. You can use a polarization medium to align the photons of the EM radiation. So that the electrical component of the radiation points in one direction.
Incidentally, you do the following: You block half of the radiation and turn the other half at the edges of the polarizer in the desired direction.
Then these steps are repeated on your slits. If the polarization direction of the polarizer and your slits match, the light passes through. If the polarizer is turned 90°, you have no chance.
TL;DR To make the process a little easier for you to understand: Two polarization foils rotated by 90° to each other do not let any light through. If you now insert another foil between them that is only rotated by 45°, light will come out at the back again. The conclusion can only be that each of the foils rotates a part of the light into the desired polarization plane; the closer the photons are to the direction of the foil with their electric field component, the more, and zero percent if they are perpendicular to each other. TL;DR

Young's interference experiment does not specifically require transverse waves, but it does require waves that exhibit coherence and can interfere. The experiment works based on the principle of superposition of waves, which is not exclusive to transverse waves. To make this clear, imagine you're standing on the shore of a calm lake and you toss two stones into the water at the same time, a small distance apart. Both stones create circular ripples (waves) that spread outward.
There are two scenarios here. The ripples on the water can represent any type of wave (light, sound, etc.). These ripples can overlap and create patterns of constructive (higher waves) and destructive (flat areas) interference, just like in Young's experiment.
When the ripples meet, they either add up (constructive interference, creating bigger waves) or cancel out (destructive interference, making flat spots). This is similar to how light waves create bright and dark fringes in Young's experiment.
If the ripples on the lake (water waves) are like transverse waves, the water moves up and down, perpendicular to the direction the wave is spreading.
If the ripples were like sound waves (longitudinal waves), imagine the water "squishing" and "stretching" in the direction the wave is moving (like compressing and decompressing a spring).
It doesn’t matter whether the ripples are from the water moving up and down (transverse) or squishing and stretching (longitudinal)—as long as they overlap in a consistent way, interference happens.
In the analogy, using water ripples is like using light in Young's experiment (easily visible and transverse). If you were to use sound waves, imagine those ripples being invisible but detectable with a sound meter. The same interference pattern could be measured, even if it’s not seen.

I question that if we need interaction between the two slits for the interference to happen, e.g., the two slits have to be very close to each other for the interference to happen. I will modify my question to make this point clearer.
